Terminology for "relative joins" in posets?
Let $P$ be a partially ordered set. Consider elements $a,b,x \in P$ with $a,b \leq x$. Is there special name for the smallest element $\leq x$ which is $\geq a,b$, that is, join of $a,b$ in the partially ordered subset $P_{\leq x}$? Notice that this doesn't necessarily equal the join in $P$ (namely, when the join in $P$ does not exist*). I would call it the "relative join" but maybe there is already another name. Also, is there a generally accepted notation such as $a \vee_x b$?
If $P$ has meets, then the "relative join" is already the join in $P$: Assume that $p \in P$ is above $a,b$. Then $p \wedge x \in P_{\leq x}$ is also above $a,b$, hence $a \vee_x b \leq p \wedge x \leq p$.
Categorical generalization: If products exist in a category $\mathcal{C}$, the forgetful functor from the slice category $\mathcal{C}/S \to \mathcal{C}$ has a right adjoint, namely $A \mapsto (A \times S \to S)$. Hence, the forgetful functor preserves all colimits. But when this is not the case, I am asking for the name for coproducts in $\mathcal{C}/S$, if it exists.
*Here is an example. Consider the set $P = \{(1,0),(0,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$ with pointwise $\leq$. Then the join of $(1,0),(0,1)$ does not exist in $P$. But the relative join to $(2,3)$ exists and is equal to $(2,3)$.

I think your note in the paragraph about the relative join not being necessarily equal to the join, namely when the join doesn't exist, is really the only way for that to happen, because if $a \vee b$ exists in $P$, then either $a \vee b \leq x$ and the relative join is the same, or $a \vee b \nleq x$ and then there is no relative join, since it would be a common upper bound not above their join. Anyway, I also don't know of any name for this, but I think relative join can be a good one. (Borrowed from the concept of relative complement, maybe?)

Yes it's equivalent, this is what I meant with "namely, when...".

It is a join in $\downarrow! x$, which is as short as relative join but more precise.
